# How To bind two or more header values together (angular2 Headers)

Tags: angular, header, http-headers, angular2-routing, angular2-http

I want to bind these two header value together into the ***RequestOptions***.
How can I do that

```
 let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
 let headers = new Headers({ 'XSRF-TOKEN': 'xsrf value' });
```

to the

> ```
>  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
headers.append( 'XSRF-TOKEN', 'xsrf value' );
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it to the first object. Am a fun of one liners.

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'XSRF-TOKEN', 'xsrf value' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

Comment: There is a syntax error with the headers object  { 'XSRF-TOKEN' , 'xsrf value' }  should be {'XSRF-TOKEN' : 'xsrf value'} for javascript key value pairs. It will help future users if its edited.